# WPF Page Effects

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I have a window in which a page is hosted in a Frame.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,30,0,0" ClipToBounds="True">
   <Frame x:Name="PageHostFrame" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

When I display the page, the page is loaded and made visible from code:

```
PageHostFrame.Content = ActivePage;
```

Is it possible to scroll the page into view from left to right using some fancy techniques in WPF?

For example, the page starts off at the far right of the window so the left position is off the screen, then it moves (animated) from the right to the left of the Frame it is hosted in.

1. This is the initial state where the page is not displayed.
2. Now the page is displayed.  Its starts life off the Frame and is then scrolled to fit the Frame.  So the Left position of it will be at 0.

[image: Actions]

Comment: in short you want to move grid from left to right when it is loaded..sorry i dont understand ..thats why asking you.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible, but it's a fair bit of work. You'd need to make a `VisualBrush` from the `Visual`s of your incomming and outgoing UIs, then animate them sliding across the screen, then remove the old UI screen and then switch the 'painted' UI with the actual controls.

Of course, it's a lot easier to let someone else do the work, so why not take a look at [Transitionals](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex? I've used it before and it certainly simplifies things. There are many more transitions available... think Microsoft Powerpoint transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..Sorry if i am wrong

```
 <Frame Background="White" x:Name="PageName">
    <Frame.Content>
        <Page  Background="LightBlue" > 
            <Page.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Page">                        
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.3,0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="st" X="0"></TranslateTransform>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard >
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" From="1376"   AccelerationRatio="0.3" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.6">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut"></ExponentialEase>
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>                   
            </Page.Style>
        </Page>
    </Frame.Content>
</Frame>
```

You can use scaletransform also and for above code adjust duration and width as per your requirement.Thank you.